# How can I reuse code when different applications share common functionality? - iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode4, code-reuse

I want to develop three applications which have some common functionality. Let say shopping cart functionality. I want a master app which have complete shopping cart functionality and then re-use the master app in all three applications. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Write your own [static library](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/) or framework and reuse it.

Comment: can i able to re-use xib files from static library? Can u explain more abt framework?